# Ruby Gem to create xlsx using template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, export-to-excel

I am looking for a Ruby Gem which can read an xlsx template and update certain rows in the file and save it as a new file.
Is there any Gem that does this?
I found a gem called SpreadsheetX which creates Excel files based on a template. But I don't find a documentation for the same.

Answer (score 1):

The `spreadsheetx` gem that you have already identified does indeed appear to suit your needs—your problem instead seems to be that it doesn't have usage documentation?

In that case, take a look the specs as they illustrate how to use the gem: https://github.com/craigulliott/spreadsheetx/blob/master/spec/spreadsheetx_spec.rb

Example:

```
empty_xlsx_file = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../templates/spec.xlsx"
workbook = SpreadsheetX.open(empty_xlsx_file)

workbook.worksheets.last.update_cell(9, 9, Time.now)
workbook.worksheets.last.update_cell(1, 4, 'A string')
workbook.worksheets.last.update_cell(9, 10, 'A string')
workbook.worksheets.last.update_cell(9, 11, 10.3)
workbook.worksheets.last.update_cell(9, 12, 53)
workbook.worksheets.last.update_cell(9, 13, nil)

new_xlsx_file = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../templates/spec_various_content.xlsx"
workbook.save(new_xlsx_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [write_xlsx](https://rubygems.org/gems/write_xlsx) Gem. Its a nice gem and simple to implement.

Comment: It does not have the feature to use a template and create a new excel based on it.